# Should I upload intel from Mass Effect Infiltrator immediately, or wait until I need the Galactic Readiness?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-infiltrator

I bought Mass Effect: Infiltrator to help ease ME3 single player.  Is there any advantage to uploading intel as I get it?  I know that uploading it early means that my readiness will slowly [drain away](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53929/1351), but I'm wondering if uploading a bunch at a time decreases the bang per buck, so to speak.  Also, does holding onto intel decrease its effectiveness at improving Galactic Readiness?

Comment: I don't have any confirmation of this, but if it works like other systems, I assume that no, it won't matter if you space it out or not. But as you mentioned the decay, I suggest waiting until the end of your ME3 campaign to import them, so the decay doesn't kick in and waste them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other posts seem to indicate that readiness delays at a rate of 3% per day.  My own experiences roughly confirm this.

This means that if you don't play multiplayer for a day, you will need to collect another 12 intel in the iOS game (4 intel per 1% readiness) simply to get yourself back in the position you were in prior to taking the day off.

Since it will never go below 50% and holding onto it does not decay its value, I would recommend holding them until just prior to starting Assault the Illusive Man's Base.

Answer (score 1):

Upload it straight away...

This is because if you play a multiplayer game, only 1 game is needed, the readiness doesnt drain for that day, i also think the same applies if 2 Intels are imported from MEI as this would equal 1% and aslong as you gain readiness in a day it won't degrade.

I would personally play multiplayer to nullify the degradation as it is fun plus you gain something like 4% per Bronze completion (with deaths)

Comment: Galatic Readiness does degrade even with a 4 hour period. Yesterday I was at 100% had some things to do around the house, came back after 3-4 hours and my readiness was at 98%.

Comment: Sorry a friend told me it degrades every 24 hours... :(