# Does Galactic Readiness earned from the Datapad app decay?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-datapad

Galactic Readiness earned during multiplayer apparently [decays at 3% per day](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53934/1561). Does the readiness earned using the Mass Effect 3 Datapad app also decay? I haven't noticed any decay in the 3 days I've been using it, but the decay might be very small or take longer to kick in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Galactic Readiness decays proportionally to the speed at which it was earned.

Readiness earned while in the ME3 Datapad iOS app is accrued slowly - fractions of a percentage per hour (depending on upgrades) and will expire at even smaller fractions of a percentage per hour.

Contrast this with readiness earned during multiplayer missions which can be accrued at several percentage points in a matter of minutes and will therefore expire at a much higher rate.

I believe this accounts for the different experiences of Galactic Readiness decay: hardcore multiplayer gamers will report a loss of 6% daily whereas those who play multiplayer little to none and rely on iOS apps to boost readiness will lose 3% or even 1% daily.

Answer (score 4):

I definitely noticed Galactic Readiness decay on the days that I only used the datapad, so yes, it does decay. I am pretty sure there is no difference between Datapad readiness and readiness from other sources. You should be able to see the decay better within the datapad app because it shows readiness to .01%.

Answer (score 1):

As murgatroid99 said, it *does* decay. However, the lower your readiness, the slower your decay. So you're likely just not noticing it yet. But once you break even 75% it will become noticeable.

Also, not checking fleet progress as often seems to slow the decay down.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it decreases about 1% every 24 hours normally, but if you use datapad it is about 1% every 2 hours. I suppose this is the game makers way of keeping you using the app. And while I love it, it is a tad ridiculous...

Answer (score 0):

After setting my readiness to 100% and then checking the App again 2 hours later, readiness had fallen to 99.96%.

Extrapolating from that, decay would be roughly 1% every 6 hours.

Comment: Wait, how did you go from 0.02% decay per hour in a 2 hour period to 0,1(6)% decay per hour in a 6 hour period?